# Filter/some on list of objects in a Firestore security rule

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

In a Firestore security rule, I'm trying to check if the user attempting to create/delete a document in one collection is also the owner of that object, as marked in another collection. Basically, my data looks something like this:

- In the `users` collection, each user has a document like this:

```
{
    name: 'john',
    userItems: [
        {
            id: 'random-id',
            ...
        }, 
        ...
    ],
    ...
}
```

- In the `items` collection (which I am writing the rule for), all of the items from all of the users of the platform are there, and have Firestore IDs which correspond to the `id` keys in the elements of the `items` list of their owners. So if `john` created an item with the id `random-id`, his user document would look like the above, and there would be a new document in the `items` collection with the Firestore ID of `random-id`.

What I am trying to achieve is to create a security rule wherein a document in the `items` collection can only be updated if the user document of the currently authed user, which I can access with `get(/databases/$(database)/documents/users/$(request.auth.uid))`, has an element in their `userItems` list which has the `id` key equal to `request.resource.id`. If this were normal JS, I'd probably do something like:

```js
match /items/{item} {
    allow write: if get(/databases/$(database)/documents/users/$(request.auth.uid))
        .data
        .userItems
        .some(userItem =>
            userItem.id === request.resource.id
        )
}
```

However, the Firestore [List interface](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/rules/rules.List) is very lacklustre, and doesn't support fancy operations like `.some`, or even basic/manual looping (as far as I'm aware). I've been trying to come up with some clever way around this, but even `.join`ing the list and `.match`ing the resulting string with some fancy RegExp wouldn't work, since I'm pretty sure that maps would parse as `'[object Object]'` instead of stringifying properly.

Is there any way to do this using standard Firestore rules, without reconfiguring my DB structure?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you're trying to do isn't possible with security rules.  You will need to either change that way you represent your data (which I recommend, as a list is probably not the best representation), or add more data to satisfy your requirements.

If the the random-id is unique in the list, you should consider using a map instead of a list to represent it, so that you can do simple lookups on the [Map](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/rules/rules.Map) that becomes available in rules.  If your userItems field was a map indexed by that ID, you could instead say:

```
allow write: if get(...).data.userItems.keys().hasAny([request.resource.id]);
```

If for some reason you can't change the field, you will need to duplicate the IDs into a new list field and check it like this:

```
allow write: if get(...).data.userItemIds.hasAny([request.resource.id]);
```